# Having trouble with createElement and appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild, createelement

I have a reasonably simple idea that I would like to implement.

I have an array of objects with two properties: "id" and "name" I would like to list these in a series of "p" tags that would be within a "div".

So here is the HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="listView"></div>
</body>
```

And here is the JavaScript in the  tag:

```
sessionStorage.eventid = 2;
var playerList = [];
playerList[0].id = 0;
playerList[0].name = "Add New Player";
playerList.push({
    id: 5,
    name: "Asako"
});
playerList.push({
    id: 6,
    name: "James"
});
playerList.push({
    id: 7,
    name: "Brian"
});
playerList.push({
    id: 8,
    name: "Helmut Spargle"
});

function listAll() {
    var element = document.getElementById("listView");
    var div;
    var node;
    for (var i = 0; i < playerList.length; i++) {
        div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute("onClick", "javascript: formOver(" + playerList[i].id + ")");
        node = "<p>" + playerList[i].name + "<br />\n" +
        "<small>&nbsp</small>\n" +
        "</p>\n";
        div.appendChild(node);
        element.appendChild(div);
    }
}
window.onLoad = function(){
    listAll();
}
```

This doesn't fill the  with anything. I have put this up on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MowgliB/8NQ5u/) as well.

Have I misunderstood how Array.push works? Or something to do with appendChile and createElement?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You have two problems (look at the javascript console in your fiddle). The first is you can set a property on `playerList[0]` when `playerList[0]` is undefined. So `playerList[0].id` is invalid. Just add items with `push` as you are will all the others. Second, you can't use `appendChild` and pass it a string. You need to pass it an element. For example, an element created with `createElement`.

Comment: How do I see the console? I have never used JSFiddle before. I couldn't find the button for it.
Thank you for all of your other advice though, @MattBurland. It has worked a treat. Except now I have used `document.creatTextNode("string");` and it outputs all of the tags as strings instead of parsing them as HTML. Does that mean I will have to make a whole bunch of elements and nodes separate from one another? Or should I just use `innerHTML`?

Comment: You can use `innerHTML` if you want. For the console, depends on your browser, but F12 is a good bet. Otherwise look in the menus in your browser probably under "tools" and "web developer" or something similar. Or just Google "how to see the javascript console in browser *x*". The console is the first step in debugging, that's where your error messages will appear.

Comment: I thought you meant a console within JSFiddle itself. But now that you have said that it seems far too obvious. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems - up front, trying to set the `id` and `name` on `playerList[0]` (which doesn't exist yet) won't work.

Second, trying to add a whole "node" full of `html`, jQuery-style, doesn't work in a plain-JS world. You need to build up the individual elements.

```
sessionStorage.eventid = 2;
var playerList = [];

playerList.push({
    id: 0,
    name: "Add New Player"
});
playerList.push({
    id: 5,
    name: "Asako"
});
playerList.push({
    id: 6,
    name: "James"
});
playerList.push({
    id: 7,
    name: "Brian"
});
playerList.push({
    id: 8,
    name: "Helmut Spargle"
});

function listAll() {

    var element = document.getElementById("listView");
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var node = "some string";
    for (var i = 0; i < playerList.length; i++) {
        div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute("onClick", "formOver(" + playerList[i].id + ")");

        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = playerList[i].name;

        var br = document.createElement('br');
        p.appendChild(br);

        var small = document.createElement('small');
        small.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
        p.appendChild(small);

        div.appendChild(p);

        element.appendChild(div);
    }
}
listAll();
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/NF45y/

Comment: I went with `div.innerHTML = "<p>" + playerList[i].name + "<br />\n <small>&nbsp</small>\n </p>\n";` instead, but your answer gave me a much deeper understanding. Thank you.

Comment: Note that `div.setAttribute("onClick", "formOver(" + playerList[i].id + ")")` effectively results in `formOver(undefined)`.

Comment: I am definitely not seeing that as a problem here (with Chrome, Firefox or Opera). I get `<div onclick="javascript: formOver(5)">` and it does what it should when clicked. Just read your comment below, it may just be something I neglected in Fiddle to reduce the amount of unnecessary code to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Initially:

```
var playerList = [];
playerList[0].id = 0;
```

You should get an error here about trying to set the *id* property of *undefined*. You can do:

```
var playerList = [{}];
playerList[0].id = 0;
playerList[0].name = "Add New Player";
```

or add the object the same way the others are. Within the function;

```
function listAll() {
    var element = document.getElementById("listView");
    var div;
    var node;
    for (var i = 0; i < playerList.length; i++) {
        div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute("onClick", "javascript: formOver(" + playerList[i].id + ")");
```

Don't use setAttribute to add listeners that way, it's not how it's intended to be used and doesn't work everywhere, use DOM properties for simplicity:

```
        div.onclick = function(){...};
```

Since you are setting values inside a loop, you need to break the closure with the variables. An immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) can help:

```
        div.onclick = (function(id) {
                         return function(){formOver(id);}
                      }(playerList[i].id));
```

Don't use XML syntax in an HTML document, and there isn't much point in the '\n' unless you are going to read the markup:

```
        node = "<p>" + playerList[i].name + "<br><small>&nbsp</small></p>";
        div.appendChild(node);
```

*appendChild* expects a DOM element, not markup. Since this is the only content of the div, you can use the markup to set its *innerHTML* property (you might want to change the name of *node* to say *markup*):

```
        div.innerHTML = node;

        element.appendChild(div);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use dom properties for events. Use `addEventListener("click", function(){})`

Comment: Because its against the normal convention. It also allows adding more than one handler per element. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick

Comment: The OP is only adding one listener, it doesn't preculde the adding of other listeners for the same event, it's supported in every browser in use (try *addEventListener* in IE8), it's less code and faster. BTW, in your "fiddle" the handler calls *formOver* with a value of `undefined`. And the answer you linked to (apparently in support of "don't do this") doesn't support not doing that. ;-)